# Can't update object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Help**, please, to solve a problem. *I tried a huge number of solutions, but nothing worked.*

**My state**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countId:{quantityId:[]},
    }}
```

**CountId creates an array of objects in state. Id is taken from another component (no problem with this). *To demonstrate what is in id, you can take Product 1,Product 2.... and accordingly this.state.countId.quantityId will be
{Product 1, quantity: 1}, {Product 2, quantity: 1}***

```
CountId = (event) => {
    this.setState({
          countId:{
            ...this.state.countId,
            quantityId:
            this.state.countId.quantityId.concat({id:(event.currentTarget.id), quantity: 1})}})
  }
```

**I am using cloneDeep lodash to create a deep copy of an object.**

```
IncrementItem = () => {
  const deepIncrement = cloneDeep(this.state.countId.quantityId);
  this.setState({
    ...this.state.countId.quantityId,
    quantity: deepIncrement.map(i => i.id ).quantity + 1
})}
```

**buttons to increase or decrease the quantity and the quantity output itself**

```
     <button onClick={this.IncrementItem}>+</button>
        <div>{this.state.countId.quantityId.map(c => c.id ? c.quantity: null)}</div>
     <button onClick={this.DecrementItem}>-</button>
```

More code

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: [],
      countId:{quantityId:[]},
    };
  }

  CountId = (event) => {
    this.setState({
          countId:{
            ...this.state.countId,
            quantityId:
            this.state.countId.quantityId.concat({id:(event.currentTarget.id), quantity: 1})}})
  }

  IncrementItem = (id) => {
    const itemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.find(element => element.id ===id);
  if (itemFound) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      countId: {...this.state.countId, quantityId: 
        [{...itemFound, quantity: itemFound.quantity + 1 }, 
          ...this.state.countId.quantityId.filter(element => element.id !==id)]}
  })}
  }
DecrementItem = (id) => {
  const itemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.find(element => element.id ===id);
if (itemFound) {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    countId: {...this.state.countId, quantityId: 
      [{...itemFound, quantity: itemFound.quantity - 1 }, 
        ...this.state.countId.quantityId.filter(element => element.id !==id)]}
})}
}

 render() {
return (
<div>
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
<Route path='/store' element={<Store CountId={this.CountId}/>}/>
<Route path='/cart' element={<Cart countId={this.state.countId}/>}/>
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
</div>
)}
```

**Store**

```
export default class Store extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: "apple"
        },
        {
          id: "lemon"
        },
        {
          id: "melon"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  countId = () => {
    if (this.props.CountId) {
      this.props.CountId();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p) => {
          return (
            <div id={p.id} onClick={this.props.countId }>
              CountId 
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Cart**

```
export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
              id: "apple"
            },
            {
              id: "lemon"
            },
            {
              id: "melon"
            }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick= 
                     {()=>this.props.IncrementItem(id)} >+</button>
                        <div > 
                     {value.state.countId.quantityId.map(c => c.id ? c.quantity: 1)}</div>
                        <button  onClick= 
                     {this.props.DecrementItem} id={products.id}>-</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem in here, can you elaborate a bit more. Its a bit unclear.

Comment: @DheerajSharma I can't increase the quantity for any of the objects. I have a store and I'm trying to increase the product in the basket, but the nested object does not change in the state. quantity defaults to 1 and I can't change this value.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this line is doing, quantity: deepIncrement.map(i => i.id ).quantity + 1, is it calculating some kind of sum?

Comment: @DheerajSharma Still does not change, in console when calling IncrementItem duplicates the object, instead of changing the quantity

Comment: @DheerajSharma deepIncrement.map(i => i.id ).quantity + 1 I'm trying to change the quantity based on id, the code may seem a little strange because I tried different options and I rewrote this code here based on my last test

Comment: I see your problem now. So you want to increment the individual items quantity just like items in a cart! What you have for CountId is fine. You’ve to be more creative with naming your functions. Nevertheless. To increment the quantity of individual item first thing you’ll need to do it to pass id to the increment function

Comment: Once you’ve passed the id to increment function then you’ll need to iterate on quantityId array and then increment it by one.

Comment: @DheerajSharma I misunderstood you a little =( Could you write this as a code based on my code and as an answer to the question, so that I can count as the correct answer

Comment: I’ve added an answer, not the most optimum way to do it, but hope you got my point  as in how you may achieve it.

Comment: You have to increment quantity of individual items or all the items in that list?

Comment: @DheerajSharma You have an interesting code, but unfortunately it also does not change the quantity

Comment: There’s a list of objects in your quantityId, right. You wanna update quantity of all of them or one of them? When you click that button increment?

Comment: @DheerajSharma individual. I have a shopping cart. I add any products and everything works without problems. But I can't enlarge/reduce any items.

Comment: So with this <button onClick={this.IncrementItem}>+</button>. You are not telling react to increment which item. I hope you’re understanding what I’m trying to say.

Comment: Instead you must have something like this <button onClick={() =>this.IncrementItem(id)}>+</button>

Comment: @DheerajSharma I have another state products, and in it products.id is the id of all products on the site

Comment: Then you’ll need add a bit more code for us to see or identify what exactly is wrong. With the amount of information you’ve provided. Its clear what you’re trying to achieve, but not very clear how or where is that erroneous logic.

Comment: @DheerajSharma Please check after the word more code, this is the updated code

Comment: @DheerajSharma I tweaked your example a bit, but now there are 2 problems. Quantity increases, but the object is duplicated, and if you add 3 products, then the quantity will be 321, and there will be 3 objects in the console, the first object will have quantity: 3, the second object will have quantity: 2, the third object will have quantity : 1.
If you add a second product to the cart, then it does not increase, that is, the quantity of only one increases.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code. for starters, 1. your variable names and naming conventions need to be updated to make code more readable. 2. Maintain single source of truth when dealing with state. 3. Render your html component based on your state, and not just any value, for example here {value.state.countId.quantityId.map(c => c.id ? c.quantity: 1)}, should be {this.state.countId.quantityId.map(c => c.id ? c.quantity: 1)} and, other minor issues. Adding a sample in comment for your reference.

Comment: @DheerajSharma Sir, your code is interesting, but it means that I need to rewrite the entire architecture of my site, I have a large architecture and everything works fine. What I wrote to you as an example is just for demonstration. Your code currently calls what I indicated above.

Comment: nope you  don't need to rewrite everything. just take the pieces you need for yourself. like have a look at how addToCart and removeToCart methods are functioning, try understanding the piece there, and you should be able to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: @DheerajSharma I understand, thank you, I will count your correct answer as I do.

Comment: Also this should be p.id <button onClick= {()=>this.props.IncrementItem(p.id)} >+</button>, instead of just id on your increment decrement buttons

Comment: @DheerajSharma I remember, thanks. addToCart(id) id is it from products.id?

Comment: @DheerajSharma Thank you, I will study now, I really want to figure it out because it took me a lot of time. By the way my problem was in [inside object] in setState

Comment: Sure. The issue as per me in your code is in how you are updating the list quantityId in your state.

Comment: @DheerajSharma I started testing your code recently and there are some problems: 1) Only the first item is incremented.
2) If you increase another product, then the first product increases and in the total amount I can see that when adding 2 products, the price of 4 products in my basket, not two, if you increase the quantity of 2 products, then the quantity of the first product will increase, and not the second, and the total price will increase immediately as if 2 of each product were added 2

Comment: when you say my code, which part of code you’re talking about and what exactly you’ve tried, if you could share some code snippets i would be able to help better. You can try out the code that’s in comment here. https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-marco-w607ve I don’t see any such issue that you’ve mentioned in this. Please share your implementation.

Comment: @DheerajSharma in your code, products as a variable that you copy to state. I have products data that comes from GraphQl. Now I tried to copy your code, which would work with my code and for further integration under my code, but I even just lost the button)))

Comment: @DheerajSharma There is a huge amount of data for each product. To increase / decrease the product, only the id is needed, which I compare with the id of the added product (to which I add quantity). The whole site including the shopping cart works fine for me, but the problem with it seems at first glance an easy task to increase / decrease the product. With Component DidMount I create products. Could you write a solution using the example of my primary code? Exactly in IncrementItem and DecrementItem

Comment: I have added another answer updating your code. check it out.

Comment: @DheerajSharma This code is much better, only the last product is corrected for me and as before, if you add 2 or more products, then each product will be 2

Comment: What did you meant by “ only the last product is corrected for me and as before, if you add 2 or more products, then each product will be 2” ? Can you explain,  it should be working fine I think if you’ve configured everything  else correctly

Comment: @DheerajSharma The questions were in my code and integration. Thanks a lot everything works great! I figured out how to do it!

Comment: @DheerajSharma Hello, if you want to help me with another question, I will also count as the correct answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740807/active-class-for-react-js-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your corrected code as per your ask, but i still feel you must correct the function names to make it more concise and readable.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Routes } from "react-router";
// import Store from "./Store";
// import Cart from "./Cart"
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: [],
      countId: { quantityId: [] },
    };
    this.IncrementItem = this.IncrementItem.bind(this);
    this.DecrementItem = this.DecrementItem.bind(this)
  }

  CountId = (event) => {
    const id = event.currentTarget.id
    this.IncrementItem(id)
  }

  IncrementItem = (id) => {
    const itemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.find(element => element.id === id);
    if (itemFound) {
      const indexOfItemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.indexOf(itemFound)
      this.setState({
        countId: {
          ...this.state.countId,
          quantityId: [
            ...this.state.countId.quantityId.slice(0, indexOfItemFound),
            { ...itemFound, quantity: itemFound.quantity + 1 },
            ...this.state.countId.quantityId.slice(indexOfItemFound + 1),
          ]
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        countId: {
          ...this.state.countId,
          quantityId: [
            ...this.state.countId.quantityId,
            { id: id, quantity: 1 }
          ]
        }
      })
    }
  }
  DecrementItem = (id) => {
    const itemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.find(element => element.id === id);
    if (itemFound) {
      const indexOfItemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.indexOf(itemFound)
      if (itemFound.quantity > 1) {
        this.setState({
          countId: {
            ...this.state.countId,
            quantityId: [
              ...this.state.countId.quantityId.slice(0, indexOfItemFound),
              { ...itemFound, quantity: itemFound.quantity - 1 },
              ...this.state.countId.quantityId.slice(indexOfItemFound + 1),
            ]
          }
        })
      }
      else {
        this.setState({
          countId: {
            ...this.state.countId,
            quantityId: [
              ...this.state.countId.quantityId.filter(element => element.id !== id)
            ]
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/store' element={<Store CountId={this.CountId} />} />
            <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart countId={this.state.countId} IncrementItem={this.IncrementItem} DecrementItem={this.DecrementItem} />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;

class Store extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: "apple"
        },
        {
          id: "lemon"
        },
        {
          id: "melon"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/cart">Goto cart</Link>
        {this.state.products.map((p) => {
          return (
            <div id={p.id} onClick={this.props.CountId}>
              CountId - {p.id} - Click on me
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.countId.quantityId.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.IncrementItem(item.id)}>+</button>
              <div >
                {`Item is ${item.id} with quantity ${item.quantity}`}
              </div>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.DecrementItem(item.id)}>-</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong here.

```
IncrementItem = () => {
  const deepIncrement = cloneDeep(this.state.countId.quantityId);
  this.setState({
    ...this.state.countId.quantityId,
    quantity: deepIncrement.map(i => i.id ).quantity + 1
})}
```

May be you can try this.

```
IncrementItem = (id) => {
  const itemFound = this.state.countId.quantityId.find(element => element.id ===id);
if (itemFound) {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    countId: {…this.state.countId, quantityId: [{…itemFound, itemFound.quantity +1 }, …this.state.countId.quantityId.filter(element => element.id !==id)]}
})}
}
```

---

### Adding a clean implementation for your reference,

App.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Routes } from "react-router";
import Store from "./Store";
import Cart from "./Cart"
import {
BrowserRouter,
Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

const products = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Lemon"
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Melon"
}
]

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    products: [...products],
    cartItems: [],
  };
  this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this);
  this.removeFromCart = this.removeFromCart.bind(this);
}

addToCart(id) {
  const foundItem = this.state.cartItems.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (foundItem) {
    const indexOfFoundItem = this.state.cartItems.indexOf(foundItem)
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      cartItems: [
        ...this.state.cartItems.slice(0, indexOfFoundItem),
        { ...foundItem, quantity: foundItem.quantity + 1 },
        ...this.state.cartItems.slice(indexOfFoundItem + 1)
      ]
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      cartItems: [
        ...this.state.cartItems,
        { ...this.state.products.find(product => product.id === id), quantity: 1 }
      ]
    })
  }
}

removeFromCart(id) {
  const foundItem = this.state.cartItems.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (foundItem) {
    const indexOfFoundItem = this.state.cartItems.indexOf(foundItem)
    if (foundItem.quantity > 1) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        cartItems: [
          ...this.state.cartItems.slice(0, indexOfFoundItem),
          { ...foundItem, quantity: foundItem.quantity - 1 },
          ...this.state.cartItems.slice(indexOfFoundItem + 1)
        ]
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        cartItems: [
          ...this.state.cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
        ]
      })
    }
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/store' element={
              <Store 
                  products={this.state.products}
                  addToCart={this.addToCart} 
              />
            } 
          />
          <Route path='/cart' element={
              <Cart 
                cartItems={this.state.cartItems} 
                addToCart={this.addToCart} 
                removeFromCart={this.removeFromCart} 
              />
            } 
          />
          <Route path='/' element={
              <Home 
                products={this.state.products} 
                cartItems={this.state.cartItems} 
                addToCart={this.addToCart} 
                removeFromCart={this.removeFromCart} 
              />
            } 
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

---

Home.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Store from "./Store";

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Store</h1>
        <hr />
        <div>
          Your Cart
          <Cart
            cartItems={this.props.cartItems}
            addToCart={this.props.addToCart}
            removeFromCart={this.props.removeFromCart}
          />
          <hr />
          Available products
          <Store
            products={this.props.products}
            addToCart={this.props.addToCart}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Store.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Store extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{maxWidth:"600px"}}>
        Product List, <Link to={'/cart'}>Click here for cart</Link>, <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
        <hr />
        {this.props.products.map((product, index) => {
          return (
            <div id={product.id} key={index}>
              {`${product.id}. ${product.name}`} 
              <button onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(product.id)}>Add to cart</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Cart.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{maxWidth:"600px"}}>
        Choosed Items, <Link to={'/store'}>Click here for products</Link>, <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
        <hr />
        { this.props.cartItems.length === 0 ? 
          "Nothing is addded to the cart" : 
          this.props.cartItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div id={item.id} key={index} >
                {`Product: ${item.name}, Quantity: ${item.quantity}`}
                <button onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(item.id)}>Add one</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.removeFromCart(item.id)}>Remove</button>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Let me know if this helps, or if you have any doubts around this.
[Play with it Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-marco-w607ve)